# Constructing $(\Bbb N,+)$ via Peano function algebra duality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, set-theory, foundations, natural-numbers

In the next section we outline a $\text{ZF}$ construction of the natural numbers under addition using a 'duality' argument (the choice of the word *duality* is subjective and has no formal meaning).

Although I am not providing all the details, I am looking for a foundational proof verification of the step-by-step logic exposition.

> If there is an error please respond by explaining it in an answer.

> An expansion of the proof detail can also be provided in an answer.

Also, if someone wants me to expand on the sketched theory please make a comment - I will then attempt to provide the argument details in an answer.

---

Given:

$\;$ The set $\omega$ of finite ordinals.

$\;$ The successor mapping $S: \omega \to \omega$ given by

$\quad S: \alpha \mapsto \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$

satisfies

$\quad S \text{ is injective}$

$\quad \text{The image of } S \text{ is equal to } \omega \setminus \{\emptyset\}$

$\quad \text{If } \emptyset \in \nu \subset \omega \text{ and } S(\nu) \subset \nu \text{ then } \nu = \omega$

(c.f. the Peano axioms)

Let $\mathcal A$ denote the [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) of all injective endomorphisms on the set $\omega$.

Let

$\quad \mathcal G = \{T \in \mathcal A \mid T \circ S = S \circ T\}$

Proposition 1: If $T, U \in \mathcal G$ then $T \circ U \in \mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G$ is a monoid.

Using recursion we define a function $\tau: \omega \to \mathcal G$ as follows:

$\quad \tau(\emptyset) = id_{\omega}$

$\quad \tau(S(n)) = S \circ \tau(n)$

The principle of induction is used to prove many of the following statements but we'll usually gloss over it, perhaps just pointing the way to nailing down the induction step.

Proposition 2: For every $n \in \omega$ there exists one and only one $T \in \mathcal G$ such that $T(\emptyset) = n$.
Proof sketch:
Besides induction the proof requires building the endomophism using recursion. $\quad \blacksquare$

We agree to denote $\tau(n)$ by $S^n$; we have

Theorem 3: The function $\tau$ is a bijective mapping and $S^n$ is defined by

$\quad \emptyset \mapsto n$

Proof sketch:
Write as true $S^n(\emptyset) = n$ and $S^{S(n)} = S \circ S^n$. $\quad \blacksquare$

Theorem 4: Composition is a commutative binary operation for the monoid $\mathcal G$.
Proof sketch:
Write as true $S^n \circ S^m = S^m \circ S^n$. Then

$\quad \displaystyle S^n \circ S^{S(m)} = S^n \circ (S \circ S^m) = (S^n \circ S) \circ S^m = (S \circ S^n) \circ S^m = S \circ (S^n  \circ S^m) =  S^{S(m)}  \circ S^n $
$\blacksquare$

Theorem 5: The [cancellation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) holds true for the monoid $\mathcal G$.
Proof:
Suppose $S^k \circ S^m = S^k \circ S^n$. Since the injective mapping $S^k$ has a left inverse we conclude that  $S^m = S^n$.
$\blacksquare$

Theorem 6: Let $S^m, S^n \in \mathcal G$ with $m \ne n$. Then $m \subsetneq n \text{ XOR } n \subsetneq m$.
Moreover, if say $m \subsetneq n$ then there exists $k \in N$ such $S^m \circ S^k = S^n$.
Proof sketch:
Using recursion we construct the sequence

$\quad \bigr(\; (S^m, S^{\emptyset}),(S^m, S^{\{\emptyset\}}),\dots,(S^m, S^k),\dots \;\bigr)$

and thereby equate (using induction)

$\quad \bigr(\; S^m \circ S^{\emptyset}, S^m \circ S^{\{\emptyset\}}, \dots,S^m \circ S^k, \dots \;\bigr)$

with

$\quad \bigr(\; S^m, S^{S(m)}, \dots, S^n,\dots \;\bigr)$

which completes the proof. $\quad \blacksquare$

We have constructed the monoid $(\mathcal G,\circ)$ and derived the properties making it isomorphic to the natural numbers under addition. We can also bijectively bring composition of functions in $\mathcal G$ to the set $\omega$ calling it addition; for $m,n \in \omega$,

$\quad \displaystyle m + n = \tau^{-1}(S^m \circ S^n) = S^m(S^n(\emptyset))$

so that we can write

$\quad \displaystyle S^m \circ S^n = S^{m+n}$

**My work and motivation**

I made another attempt at this before (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3044090/432081)), but wanted to try again. I also wanted to write this up as a response to Andrés E. Caicedo [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15871/432081), suggesting that there is a fourth way of defining addition.

Comment: Let me try to summarize this a bit more snappily. The key lemma is that for each $n\in\omega$ there is exactly one function $T_n$ such that $T_n(0)=n$ and $T_n(S(x))=S(T_n(x))$ for all $x\in \omega$. Addition of finite ordinals can then alternately be defined by $$(a,b)\mapsto c\quad\iff\quad T_a\circ T_b=T_c.$$ Is this an accurate summary? (It's correct, btw.) If so, I think the initial part about well-ordering $\omega$ is kind of a red herring.

Comment: Note that this won't work in too much generality: there is no magma of functions on $\mathbb{N}$ which is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}; exp)$, since $exp$ is nonassociative but function composition is associative. But $exp$ can be built via recursion.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, and we can capture the properties of $(\omega,+)$ that determine it (up to isomorphism) by applying logic to the function algebra $\mathcal G$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I removed the red herring...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, $\quad \quad (a,b)\mapsto c\quad\iff\quad c = \omega \setminus \text{Image}(T_a\circ T_b)$

Answer (score 1):

Here we focus on the key lemma (see Noah Schweber's comment) that allows us to determine the structure of $(\Bbb N, +)$ (up to isomorphism) by analyzing an algebra of functions.

Lemma: For every $n \in \omega$ there exists one and only one function $T: \omega \to \omega$ satisfying the following two properties,

$\tag 1 T(\emptyset) = n$
$\tag 2 T \circ S = S \circ T$

Proof

**Existence:**
Using the recursion theorem we define $T$ by

$\tag 3 T(\emptyset) = n$
$\tag 4 T(S(m)) = S(T(m))$

Clearly this function $T$ satisfies both $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$.

We denote this recursively defined function $T$ by $T_n$.

**Uniqueness:**
Let $T$ satisfy both $\text{(1})$ and $\text{(2})$.
Using induction over the domain we show that $T = T_n$.
Base Case $m = \emptyset$: Trivial
Step Case:
Assume  $T(m) = T_n(m)$.
Then
$\quad T(S(m)) = (T \circ S) (m) = (S \circ T) (m)= S(T(m)) = S(T_n(m)) = T_n(S(m))$

This completes the proof. $\quad \blacksquare$

Comment: Part of the motivation of writing this was looking over [ZFC Addition Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779244/zfc-addition-function) - it generated much more interest than this question which is a bit puzzling.